# Basic querying in freebase

Tags: information-retrieval, freebase

I am tinkering with Freebase, and trying things with the query editor and everything looks great. I'm still reading the fine manual, but can't seem to get the point if this may be used as a web search replacement for showing refined data to the user. The main question is:

If {q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>, q<sub>3</sub> ....} be the query the user submits - how do I programatically map each query term to the freebase query key:value pair?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can entirely replace the current search engines as of now.I have just written a blog post for handling a basic query(more will follow) in C# for freebase.
http://2guysfrommumbai.wordpress.com/

If you like the java stuff you can go to,
https://github.com/narphorium/freebase-java-api
this is a more complete api,and i have used it with good success.

You can append multiple queries using q1,q2,q3 as parameters,more details are available on the freebase developer site.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man ... I'm in class right now, 'll check back once its over!